# Basic Python Struggles

Tags: python

I'm making a maths skills testing program and was wondering if there's a way in which i can make random questions appear in my program instead of having to do this every single time;

```
import time
start = time.time()
userinput = input("\nWhat is 11+7?")
if userinput=="18":
    print("\nNot bad, lets try something a little harder...")
    print('It took you {0:0.1f} seconds to answer the 
question'.format(time.time() - start))
else:
    print("\nAt least you got one right")
    print('It took you {0:0.1f} seconds to answer the 
question'.format(time.time() - start))
    exit()
```

Also, how can i add a while statement into this? I would also like to add a def function in if possible. Thanks.

Comment: You could use the random library, to generate two random numbers, assign them to variables, print them like `print(var1, "+", var2)` then run that as a piece of code: `var3 = var1+var2`, then check it using an if statement: `if input == var3: do stuff`.

Comment: The title should represent what your question is about but whether you are good in coding or not.

Comment: Hi, I did a rollback on your question. You are not supposed to change it to a new question after you got answers, because doing so would invalidate the answers. Please ask a new question instead and reference this one if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a random operator and random numbers:

```
import operator
import random

ops = {'+': operator.add,
       '-': operator.sub}  # add mul and div if you wish

keys_tuple = tuple(ops.keys())
num_a = random.randint(1, 10)  # use larger range if you wish
num_b = random.randint(1, 10)  # use larger range if you wish
op = random.choice(keys_tuple)

print('{}{}{}=?'.format(num_a, op, num_b))
expected_answer = ops[op](num_a, num_b)
user_answer = int(input())
if user_answer == expected_answer:
    print('Correct')
else:
    print('Wrong')
```

As for the `while`, simple wrap the whole code in a `while True` loop that breaks if the user inputs a certain value (ie `'quit'`, which will currently raise a `ValueError`)

Comment: That's great thanks! But how would i make it so that the questions keep being asked? or that there's different levels with harder questions?

Comment: @user9041128 As I mentioned in the answer below the code, you can wrap the entire thing in a `while True`. As for the "levels" it's up to you to implement by a logic you decide on, for example increase the range of the random numbers. I can't write an entire game for you in a SO answer.

Comment: please can you check my updated question code? thanks :)

Comment: please can you check it

Answer (score 0):

So you want to make math problems basically? Here is what you need to do for that:

Make two random ints - step 1
See if the answer adds up to the answer - step 2

You can now try solving it yourself. In case you need some help, you can come back and see this:

```
from random import randint

def get_random_int(): # Function to get random int
    random_num = randint(1, 20) #Gets an int between 1 and 20. Change if needed

    return random_num

def check_answer(first_number, second_number, input_ans): # function to check answer correction
  if (first_number + second_number == input_ans):
      return "Correct answer!"
  else:
      return "Try again!"

number_1 = get_random_int()
number_2 = get_random_int()

user_input = input("What is %s plus %s?" % ( str(number_1), str(number_2) ))
# Wrap in str() to display as string

print( check_answer(number_1, number_2, int(user_input) ) )
# Wrap in int() because it is a number
```

And if you need this to loop constantly, wrap this in a `while True:` endless loop. Be sure to give a way to exit from it! (Use `break` in the code to exit from loop)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: please can you check my updated question code thanks :)

Comment: Your code has a lot of bugs too... Maybe ask this in another question and revert back this one? Since people spent time answering that one :). You can ask this in another one

Comment: @KidDoesCodingAndHasNoFriends I agree, OP should not have changed the question. I did a rollback.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost entirely `@DeepSpace's` code, but to answer your question of how to add the `while` loop, just throw all of the code after the initial definitions into the scope of a `while` loop:

```
import operator
import random

ops = {'+': operator.add,
       '-': operator.sub}  # add mul and div if you wish

keys_tuple = tuple(ops.keys())

while True:

    num_a = random.randint(1, 10)  # use larger range if you wish
    num_b = random.randint(1, 10)  # use larger range if you wish
    op = random.choice(keys_tuple)

    print('{}{}{}=?'.format(num_a, op, num_b))
    expected_answer = ops[op](num_a, num_b)
    user_answer = int(input())
    if user_answer == expected_answer:
        print('Correct')
    else:
        print('Wrong')
```